# How to draw LDA decision boundary given a fixed covariance matrix

Tags: bayesian, linear-model

I have been searching all over the internet and have not found an answer that specifically answers my question, so I apologize in advance if this has already been answered somewhere else and I did not see it.

I am trying to figure out how to draw a 2-class decision boundary given the assumption that the covariance matrix Σ = Σi = σ^2I. I have computed that μ1 = [-0.221, 0.326] and μ2 = [0.076, 0.683]. I have gotten the scalar from the covariance matrix equal to σ^2 = 0.1256. The prior probabilities are both 0.5. We are assuming a Gaussian distribution.

I understand that I am supposed to set two equations equal to each other in the form of gi(x) = gk(x) and solve. The equation is as follows:

```
gi(x) = (μi.T/σ^2)x - (μi.T * μi)/2σ^2 + lnP(ωi)
```

This is the part where I am stuck and where I did not see an answer to my question. I do not understand how I am supposed to get points (in the form [x0, y0] , [x1, y1]) with which I can plot a linear decision boundary from here. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we solve $g_i(x)=g_k(x)$, we'll obtain the following hyperplane equation:
$$(\mu_i-\mu_k)^Tx+\underbrace{(||\mu_k||-||\mu_i||)/2+\ln (P(w_i)/P(w_k))}_{\text{constant wrt x}}=0$$
which is in the form of a hyperplane equation: $w^Tx+b=0$; And it is your boundary equation. Since the dataset is 2D, the boundary will be a line of the form $ax+by+c=0$; you can plot this line in any way you like.